# When I extract a tar file, all the files/folders have 777 permissions

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, tar

I run Debian. I have a tar archive that, when extracted, assigns 777 permissions to all files/folders in it. I believe this has to do with the fact that I'm root, but is there a way to make it so they default to 755/644?

```
tar xfz jaws-complete-0.8.18.tar.gz
```

I tried editing `/etc/login.defs`, logged out and back in but no change.

I noted there is a `--no-same-permissions` option, but is there a way around using this?

Comment: Please capitalize your posts properly (i.e., use "I" instead of "i", etc.) – that could've been a reason you could not post the initial version of this question. You should not insert dummy text to get around that filter. Thanks.

Comment: I wondered about that, i will keep in mind that for next time, -1 accepted.

Comment: Perhaps `umask`.

Comment: i believe that is handeled by /etc/login.defs

Comment: If you create a file and directory using `touch` and `mkdir` what permission you are getting ?

Comment: Tar commonly applies the perms and ownerships that are inside the archive.  The only way I can think of to make this different by default is mount-options on the file-system you're extracting to. Is it, by any chance, FAT or some such?

Comment: probs, as yes when i touch or mkdir it is correct permissions

Answer (score 1):

It's likely your tar file contains files with 777 permission. Run `tar tvfz jaws-complete-0.8.18.tar.gz` to verify. If that's the case, you just have to do a `chmod -R go-w ...`